# After publishing on IIS POST response does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, web-config, localhost

I finished my asp.net web application and tried already to do a post request with postman but after publishing it on IIS i am not getting the same result as in my local machine. I already looked if the problem has to do with my connection string to the database, but there is no problem with this. I really don't know how to fix this.

I added the following headers:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost, System.Web.Http.ActionName("~/SaveComment")]
[System.Web.Http.Route("~/SaveComment")]


public bool SaveComment(Comment comment)
{
  if (comment == null)
  {
      return false;
  }

     return CommentProcessor.ProcessAddComment(comment);

 }
```

In local i am getting a true response, but on the server it shows me false via postman. Do you have any idea?

Comment: whats the error? put error here.

Comment: There's no explicit error. It does not write back via POST in to my database after publishing the application on iis.

Comment: Always use exception handling with `Try-Catch` blocks in your code. It is a bad practice of not handling exceptions. I believe that in your case, it could be a routing error. If you find any errors, please post that here.

Comment: I do have exception handling in my code, but after publishing it on IIS, i am not able to debug it at all.

Comment: It's a little unclear, so can you confirm the Postman request works on your local machine or are you hitting your app a different way locally?

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a POST request. Possibly the `comment` parameter has null in it and because of that you are seeing `false` as the response.

Try adding `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter. Something like this:

`public bool SaveComment([FromBody] Comment comment)`